# Google font not displaying

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates, google-fonts

I am trying to get a Google font to load from css to my html template for my application.  Can't get the "Upload schtuff" to assume the Bangers font. Here's the base.html:

```html
{% load static %}
   <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <title>{% block title %}Upload Schtuff{% endblock %}</title>
       <head>
            <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bangers&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
      </head>
      <body>
          <div>
            <h1><a href="/">Upload schtuff </a></h1>
            </div>
      </body>
</html>

Here's the static/uploader/style.css:
'''
h1 a, h2 a
{
 color: #714D91;
 font-family: 'Bangers', cursive;
}
'''

I've also tried importing the font to the style sheet with 
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bangers&display=swap');

Also tried importing it to the .html file
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bangers&display=swap');
</style>
```

It's got to be my link href lines, right?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The link will need to start with the protocol i.e. `https:` e.g. `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bangers&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Comment: @MikePoole not it does not. “Implicit protocol”, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#Examples_of_absolute_URLs

Comment: Works fine with the URLs given, and the shown style applied - https://jsfiddle.net/0L5wqfsd/

Comment: @04FS Understood but I am not sure why folk choose to use implicit protocols when it is not supported by older browsers. Surely we should be coding for the widest base.

Comment: @MikePoole if we are talking about IE <= 8, those would only support EOT format web fonts, which are not even included by the given Google stylesheet. And I wouldn’t know any other browsers that do not support this, that could still be considered relevant these days.

Comment: Thanks, yeah.  I'm doing it in a django application.  Can't get it to work on the webserver. Using Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it to work! This was my first time adding multiple Css files... and I was missing this in my settings.py file

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]

LOL, thanks for being a good community and standing by me while I solve my own problems!